# How to animate and propertly intepolate a QML rotation transform in 3D

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, qml, glm-math

This code sample here:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Item {
    width: 200; height: 200
    Rectangle {
        width: 100; height: 100
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "#00FF00"
        Rectangle {
            color: "#FF0000"
            width: 10; height: 10
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.right: parent.right
        }
    }
}
```

Will produce this output:

[image: step 1]

Now I want to apply a 3D rotation from the center of this green rectangle. First, I want to rotate on X by -45 degrees (bowing down), then on Y by -60 degrees (turning left).

I used the following c++ code snipped using GLM on the side to help me calculate the axis and angle:

```
// generate rotation matrix from euler in X-Y-Z order
// please note that GLM uses radians, not degrees
glm::mat4 rotationMatrix = glm::eulerAngleXY(glm::radians(-45.0f), glm::radians(-60.0f));

// convert the rotation matrix into a quaternion
glm::quat quaternion = glm::toQuat(rotationMatrix);

// extract the rotation axis from the quaternion
glm::vec3 axis = glm::axis(quaternion);

// extract the rotation angle from the quaternion
// and also convert it back to degrees for QML
double angle = glm::degrees(glm::angle(quaternion));
```

The output of this little C++ program gave me an axis of `{-0.552483, -0.770076, 0.318976}` and an angle of `73.7201`. So I updated my sample code to this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Item {
    width: 200; height: 200
    Rectangle {
        width: 100; height: 100
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "#00FF00"
        Rectangle {
            color: "#FF0000"
            width: 10; height: 10
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.right: parent.right
        }
        transform: Rotation {
            id: rot
            origin.x: 50; origin.y: 50
            axis: Qt.vector3d(-0.552483, -0.770076, 0.318976)
            angle: 73.7201
        }
    }
}
```

Which give me exactly what I wanted to see:

[image: step 2]

So far so good. Now comes the hard part. How do I animate this? For example, if I want to go from {45.0, 60.0, 0} to {45.0, 60.0, 90.0}. In other word, I want to animate from here

[image: step 2]

to here

[image: step3]

I plugged that target rotation here

```
// generate rotation matrix from euler in X-Y-Z order
// please note that GLM uses radians, not degrees
glm::mat4 rotationMatrix = glm::eulerAngleXYZ(glm::radians(-45.0f), glm::radians(-60.0f), glm::radians(90.0f);

// convert the rotation matrix into a quaternion
glm::quat quaternion = glm::toQuat(rotationMatrix);

// extract the rotation axis from the quaternion
glm::vec3 axis = glm::axis(quaternion);

// extract the rotation angle from the quaternion
// and also convert it back to degrees for QML
double angle = glm::degrees(glm::angle(quaternion));
```

which gave me an axis of `{-0.621515, -0.102255, 0.7767}` and an angle of `129.007`

So I added this animation to my sample

```
ParallelAnimation {
    running: true
    Vector3dAnimation {
        target: rot
        property: "axis"
        from: Qt.vector3d(-0.552483, -0.770076, 0.318976)
        to: Qt.vector3d(-0.621515, -0.102255, 0.7767)
        duration: 4000
    }
    NumberAnimation {
        target: rot;
        property: "angle";
        from: 73.7201; to: 129.007;
        duration: 4000;
    }
}
```

Which 'almost' works. The problem is, if you try it, you will see that the rotation goes completely off its desired rotation axis for the first half of the animation, but fixes itself for the last half of the animation. The starting rotation is good, the target rotation is good, but whatever that happens in between is not good enough. It is better if I use smaller angles like 45 degrees instead of 90 degrees, and is going to be worst if I use larger angles like 180 degrees instead of 45 degrees, where it just spins in random directions until it reaches its final targets.

How do I get this animation to look right between the start rotation and the target rotation?

------------------- EDIT -------------------

I am adding one more criteria: The answer I am looking for **must absolutely provide an identical output** as the screenshots I provided above.

For example, splitting the 3 rotation axis in 3 separate rotation transforms doesn't give me the right results

```
    transform: [
        Rotation {
            id: zRot
            origin.x: 50; origin.y: 50;
            angle: 0
        },
        Rotation {
            id: xRot
            origin.x: 50; origin.y: 50;
            angle: -45
            axis { x: 1; y: 0; z: 0 }
        },
        Rotation {
            id: yRot
            origin.x: 50; origin.y: 50;
            angle: -60
            axis { x: 0; y: 1; z: 0 }
        }
    ]
```

Will give me this:

[image: incorrect]

Which is incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my own problem. I completely forgot that Qt doesn't do spherical linear interpolation!!! As soon as I did my own slerp function, it all worked perfectly.

Here's my code for those who are seeking the answer:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {

    function angleAxisToQuat(angle, axis) {
        var a = angle * Math.PI / 180.0;
        var s = Math.sin(a * 0.5);
        var c = Math.cos(a * 0.5);
        return Qt.quaternion(c, axis.x * s, axis.y * s, axis.z * s);
    }

    function multiplyQuaternion(q1, q2) {
        return Qt.quaternion(q1.scalar * q2.scalar - q1.x * q2.x - q1.y * q2.y - q1.z * q2.z,
                             q1.scalar * q2.x + q1.x * q2.scalar + q1.y * q2.z - q1.z * q2.y,
                             q1.scalar * q2.y + q1.y * q2.scalar + q1.z * q2.x - q1.x * q2.z,
                             q1.scalar * q2.z + q1.z * q2.scalar + q1.x * q2.y - q1.y * q2.x);
    }

    function eulerToQuaternionXYZ(x, y, z) {
        var quatX = angleAxisToQuat(x, Qt.vector3d(1, 0, 0));
        var quatY = angleAxisToQuat(y, Qt.vector3d(0, 1, 0));
        var quatZ = angleAxisToQuat(z, Qt.vector3d(0, 0, 1));
        return multiplyQuaternion(multiplyQuaternion(quatX, quatY), quatZ)
    }

    function slerp(start, end, t) {

        var halfCosTheta = ((start.x * end.x) + (start.y * end.y)) + ((start.z * end.z) + (start.scalar * end.scalar));

        if (halfCosTheta < 0.0)
        {
            end.scalar = -end.scalar
            end.x = -end.x
            end.y = -end.y
            end.z = -end.z
            halfCosTheta = -halfCosTheta;
        }

        if (Math.abs(halfCosTheta) > 0.999999)
        {
            return Qt.quaternion(start.scalar + (t * (end.scalar - start.scalar)),
                                 start.x      + (t * (end.x      - start.x     )),
                                 start.y      + (t * (end.y      - start.y     )),
                                 start.z      + (t * (end.z      - start.z     )));
        }

        var halfTheta = Math.acos(halfCosTheta);
        var s1 = Math.sin((1.0 - t) * halfTheta);
        var s2 = Math.sin(t * halfTheta);
        var s3 = 1.0 / Math.sin(halfTheta);
        return Qt.quaternion((s1 * start.scalar + s2 * end.scalar) * s3,
                             (s1 * start.x      + s2 * end.x     ) * s3,
                             (s1 * start.y      + s2 * end.y     ) * s3,
                             (s1 * start.z      + s2 * end.z     ) * s3);
    }

    function getAxis(quat) {
        var tmp1 = 1.0 - quat.scalar * quat.scalar;
        if (tmp1 <= 0) return Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        var tmp2 = 1 / Math.sqrt(tmp1);
        return Qt.vector3d(quat.x * tmp2, quat.y * tmp2, quat.z * tmp2);
    }

    function getAngle(quat) {
        return Math.acos(quat.scalar) * 2.0 * 180.0 / Math.PI;
    }

    width: 200; height: 200
    Rectangle {
        width: 100; height: 100
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "#00FF00"
        Rectangle {
            color: "#FF0000"
            width: 10; height: 10
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.right: parent.right
        }
        transform: Rotation {
            id: rot
            origin.x: 50; origin.y: 50
            axis: getAxis(animator.result)
            angle: getAngle(animator.result)
        }
    }

    NumberAnimation
    {
        property quaternion start: eulerToQuaternionXYZ(-45, -60, 0)
        property quaternion end: eulerToQuaternionXYZ(-45, -60, 180)
        property quaternion result: slerp(start, end, progress)
        property real progress: 0
        id: animator
        target: animator
        property: "progress"
        from: 0.0
        to: 1.0
        duration: 4000
        running: true
    }
}
```

Comment: It is really baffling because they provide a slerp function in their QQuaternion class, but is not exposed in QML: 

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquaternion.html#slerp

Comment: They really should add a QuaternionAnimation to perform this spherical linear interpolator for us, or at least expose the slerp function

Comment: why did you did this by functions only? Why not use declarative nature of QML?

Comment: But I have already implemented my own conversion utility module in C++, and exposed to QML if that's what you mean. It's just easier to do prototypes and show answers on stack overflow in javascript because people can simply copy and paste the solution and try it themselves if they want to see the result

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to this in wrong way. You can combine transformations and animate one of it. This way you will achieve exactly what you need.

Another problem I see is that you are writing about degrees and in code I see radians :).

Bottom line this should look like this:

```
    Rectangle {
        width: 100; height: 100
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "#00FF00"
        Rectangle {
            color: "#FF0000"
            width: 10; height: 10
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.right: parent.right
        }

        transform: [
            Rotation {
                id: zRot
                origin.x: 50; origin.y: 50;
                angle: 0
            },
            Rotation {
                id: xRot
                origin.x: 50; origin.y: 50;
                angle: 45
                axis { x: 1; y: 0; z: 0 }
            },
            Rotation {
                id: yRot
                origin.x: 50; origin.y: 50;
                angle: 60
                axis { x: 0; y: 1; z: 0 }
            }
        ]
        NumberAnimation {
            running: true
            loops: 100
            target: zRot;
            property: "angle";
            from: 0; to: 360;
            duration: 4000;
        }
    }
```

Result is different from this one on your pictures, but this is result you've messed up degrees and radians. I used transformation described in text, not from your code.

Comment: GLM works in exclusively radians, which is why I converted my euler angles in radians (e.g. `glm::radians(45.0f)`), and in the end, I'm converting it back in degrees (e.g. `glm::degrees(glm::angle(quaternion))`)

Comment: And no, I cannot accept your answer. Your code does not give me exactly the result from my images above. But you made me realize a mistake I made. The angles are using the right hand rule, which means that my angles were supposed to be -45 degree and -60 degrees. Thank you for this :-)

Comment: I updated my C++ code with comments about the degree-to-radians and converting back from radians-to-degree. And added the criteria I am looking for that the output must be **identical** to the screenshots I provided.

Comment: I did some testing and it turns out that there is some QML bug. Rotating around X by 89 degrees and then rotation around Y by 89 degrees shows one pixel sized object (90 degree rotation shows nothing). Looks like each transformation is applied to flat object producing new flat object. IMO all transformation should be combined and then applied. Providing single transformation resolves this problem, but makes thing harder to animate.

Comment: Yes, I reached the very same exact conclusion than you. Thank you @marek-r