# how to make compiz like page transition

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have Qt/QML app which shows items (pictures) on some ListView or StackView. I would like to have a transition from page to page like in Compiz Window Manager
[Compiz Window Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz)
I need some mathemathical equation, or some other explanation of how x,y,z of four corners of my object should change to have this 3D effect of cube rotation.

[image: Cube rotation]

Best,
Marek

Comment: That can be done "quite easily" with OpenGL. Qt has OpenGL support (AFAIK QML even more). Without OpenGL, you might compute the image distortions "by hand" - may be, similar like in this answer [SO: Rotate an image in C++ without using OpenCV functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56985104/7478597) although it might be better to expand this to 3d coordinates (4x4 matrices instead of 3x3 matrices).

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644373/how-to-animate-and-propertly-intepolate-a-qml-rotation-transform-in-3d might get a long way. You can also use `Maxtrix4x4` as the single transformation. Unfortunately my matrix-skills lack a bit, so here is an attempt with just `Translate` and `Rotation`: https://gist.github.com/amfasis/62181f1efcd0b3a2168b5903913a484c

Comment: @Amfasis thanks for this code.  So basically what you are saying it would be better to use Matrix4x4 from Transform instead of individual Rotation/Translate, in conjunction with NumberAnimation to have this effect. I think I have seen somewhere what individual fields of that Matrix means but I'm unable to find it now.

Comment: Yes, because the error with what I now wrote is that the z is missing, `Translate` on his own doesn't do z. So using `Matrix4x4` you can get it, but then I cannot get the rotation ánd the translation correct. Maybe try this: https://www3.nd.edu/~pbui/teaching/cse.40166.fa10/slides/Lecture_4_Transformations_and_Matrices.pdf ?