# Multipling Quaternions in Qt Quick 3D QML

Tags: qt, qml

Using Qt Quick 3D QML and without having additional C++, how could I multiply two quaternions?

I have a fixed rotation value given in quaternion (`Qt.quaternion(a,b,c)`), to which I would like to add a variable part.

Documentation is very scarce about that (I only found [quaternion](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-quaternion.html) and [Transform](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt3d-core-transform.html)) and apparently there is no "times()" property similar to the one from vector. On the C++ side, I can multiply and normalize quaternions ([QQuaternion](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qquaternion.html))

Edit: This was a problem in Qt6.0. For Qt6.4 and further there are many quaternion manipulation methods, see [Stephen Quan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74417065/9544417) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend writing your own JavaScript function doing the multiplication. One example implementation (`multiplyQuaternion()`) can be seen in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33664346/4911665) to another question.

You can also take a look into implementation of `inline const QQuaternion operator*(const QQuaternion &q1, const QQuaternion& q2)` in [QQuaternion](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/gui/math3d/qquaternion.h) class for reference when writing your own JS function.

Another possibility might be to utilize some ready-made JS implementation (if found) by importing a JS file in question into your QML.

You could also write *QObject*-based C++ wrapper which utilizes `QQuaternion` class and then expose it to *QML*. But you would have to link with Qt Gui module and write quite a lot of boilerplate code because of that one function which probably doesn't make too much sense.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt6, there are many useful methods on quaternion for multiplying with another quaternion, vector, or scalar values.

```
var a = Qt.quaternion(1 / Math.sqrt(2), 1 / Math.sqrt(2), 0, 0);
var b = Qt.quaternion(1 / Math.sqrt(2), 0, 1 / Math.sqrt(2), 0);
var c = b.times(a);
console.log(c.toString()); // QQuaternion(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5)

var a = Qt.quaternion(0.5,0.5,0.5,-0.5);
var b = Qt.vector3d(4,5,6);
var c = a.times(b);
console.log(c.toString()); // QVector3D(5, -6, -4)

var a = Qt.quaternion(1,2,3,4);
var b = 4.48;
var c = a.times(b);
console.log(c.toString()); // QQuaternion(4.48, 8.96, 13.44, 17.92)
```

See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-quaternion.html

Comment: Yes, this question is trivial since Qt 6.4. At the time of the question is was 6.0 and this did not work.